# Как сделать колонки с помощью гридов?

Tags: css

Привет!
Есть меню, где-то одна колонка, где-то 3. На скрине ниже указал как должно быть
http://take.ms/JUYou

Сделал так:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-auto-rows: 22px;
```

Но в итоге теперь везде по три колонки.  Как сделать правильно их? Может не гридами тогда, но флексы так не смогут вроде.
https://jsfiddle.net/pm14ur4L/3/

Answer (score 0):

Та, которая должна занимать 3 колонки, в стиле пропишите grid-column: 1 / 4

Comment: а нет такого в гридах, что бы универсально было?  что бы не плодить модификаторы

Comment: Универсально - это как? Он же не может угадать, что вам нужно. Если нужна универсальность, пользуйтесь гридами bootstrap.

Comment: под универсальным предполагаю так, если больше 4 элементов, то последний уходит во вторую колонку

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите, чтобы к примеру 6 блоков разбивалось на 2 колонки по 3 блока?

Comment: да, 6 элементов разбивались в 2 колонки, а если всего 3 элемента, то колонка одна всего была бы. Сейчас пока только выходит что в любом случае 3 колонки.

Comment: Если визуально разбить нужно, то :nth-child() использовать. Если группировка элементов внутри блоков, то JS.